# generating .cs files with lower language version

Tags: c#

##### Background

I'm developing an extension code for ancient dotnet system.

The system requires all `.cs` files to be in C# 6.0 Language version. Said ancient system reads `.cs` files at runtime. Therefore, the only thing I can do is to prepare 'raw' `.cs` files as-is, not as compiled `.dll` files.

##### Question

Is there a way to write `.cs` in up-to-date version, and then simply 'translate' them into older version of them?

Note that `TargetFramework` option does not work, as I'm not doing any compiling. I'm only trying to transform `.cs` into another `.cs`.

##### Example

```cs
namespace Test;

// code...
```

This [file scoped namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces) works in modern C# 10.0, but it fails if I try to feed it into an older system. As this feature does not exist in C# 6.0.

So, It would be better if I could:

```cs
////////// source.cs
namespace Test;

public class Class {}
//////////

// some magic happens...

////////// dist.cs
namespace Test {
    public class Class {}
}
//////////
```

Comment: The C# version for your project determines what language features are supported. It doesn't mean that you have to use all those features. You can write your C# code in a project that targets any language version but, if you only use features supported in C# 6, the files will be able to be read by anything that understands C# 6. The problem is that, without the IDE limiting what features you can use, you may inadvertently use newer features that are not supported in the version you care about.

Comment: you can defind language version in cs proj using `<LangVersion></LangVersion>`

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for your input. A bit of clarification I might add: I'm aware of that it's possible to write 6.0 compatible in the first place.

What I'm then trying to achieve is rather an automatic way to do just that without such concern at all. Sort of a babel.js for C#, for lack of a better word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your code with the version of your choice, then decompile it with [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) while setting the version of language to C# 6.0.

Comment: I guess your suggesion is the most feasible way of doing this. Thank you for your knowledge.